# How can SKIA be used to decode a jpeg image in android

Tags: android, jpeg, decoding, mjpeg, skia

I am new to android and i want to decode JPEG images for further processing. I used **BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray** but it takes a lot of time to decode. 
How can **SKIA** be used to decode JPEGs efficiently any sample codes aur link to tutorial would be appreciated

Comment: are you already using skia in the app?

Comment: Have you applied necessary optimization flags to `BitmapConfig` before decoding the resource? E.g. maybe your source is 100MB, you don't need that much memory occupied (which will result in OutOfMemoryException), you can ask to decode a downsampled image.

Comment: Optimization flags didn't really help moreover  i am decoding an image of size 1024x768 and i cant subsample it because i need the the same resolution for further processing. how can i verify that my code is using hardware jpeg decoder